# Registering event handlers for many buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a calculator which has more than 12 buttons including digits and arithmetic operations.Do I have to write it separately `document.getElementById("").value` for every button.Any alternatives?

```
    <form>
<input type="text"/>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <button id ="button1">1</button></td>
<td> <button id="button2">2</button></td>
<td> <button id="button3">3</button></td>
<td> <button id="button4">4</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <button id ="button5">5</button></td>
<td> <button id="button6">6</button></td>
<td> <button id="button7">7</button></td>
<td> <button id="button8">8</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <button id ="button9">9</button></td>
<td> <button id="button0">0</button></td>
<td> <button id="button+">+</button></td>
<td> <button id="button-">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <button id ="button*">*</button></td>
<td> <button id="button/">/</button></td>
<td> <button id="button=">=</button></td>
<td> <button id="buttonc">C</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: you can keep all calulator keywords {1,2,3,4..+-/* } in the array and const "button" and loop through for array and say if(document.getelementById("button"+arr[i])!= undefined)document.getelementById(i).value(arr[i])

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) buttons[i].onClick = function{ ... };
```

if you have more buttons which should not be affected put some class to the buttons involved and search by class name instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var buttonList = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for(var i=0; i < buttonList.length; i++){
    buttonList[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
        switch (buttonList[i].id) {
            case "button1":
            // call function for button1 here
            break;
            case "button2":
            // call function for button2 here
            break;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can keep all calculator keywords {1,2,3,4..+-/* } in the array and const "button" and loop through for array and say

```
var arr= {"1", "2", "3" .. "*", "/" };

 for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
  var element = document.getElementById("button"+arr[i]);
  if(element !=undefined){
        element.value(arr[i]) ;
    /*can add onclick event etc here also..
        element.onclick  = function() {}
     */
    }  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define one method and assign it to all the buttons

```
<td> <button id ="button1" onclick=ButtonClick(this)>1</button></td>
<td> <button id="button2" onclick=ButtonClick(this)>2</button></td>


function ButtonClick(Sender)
{
var element = document.getElementById(sender.id);
//now do any thing with this element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for IE, since IE doesn't support `addEventListener`.

```
var buttonList = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");

for(var i=0; i < buttonList.length; i++){
    var el = buttonList[i];
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener('click', btnClick, false);  //For non-IE browsers
    } else if (el.attachEvent)  {
        el.attachEvent('onclick', btnClick); //For IE
    }
}

function btnClick() {

}
```